# Swift - UITextField - Gesture recognizer delay

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer, delay, textfield

I'm using a UITextField and I'd like to trigger a function when the user is taping in the textfield, but I want to wait 1/4sec before triggering the function.

How can I do that ?

Comment: You can use  performSelector("targetMethod", withObject: nil, afterDelay: 4.0) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to create IBAction for example: changeTextField (see you screenshot)

[screenshot: create an IBAction for Editing changed event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYIZl.png)

Second add this code

```
@IBAction func changeTextField(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.functionWithDelay), object: nil)
    self.performSelector(#selector(ViewController.functionWithDelay),
                         withObject: nil,
                         afterDelay: 1/4);
}
```

Third, you function

```
func functionWithDelay() {
    print("running...")
}
```

Comment: It's not working as I want.
"functionWithDelay" is called everytime I hit the keyboard.
I'd like the function to be called only when I'm not tapping for longer than 1/4sec

Comment: code update: I've add call to cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget if hit the keyboard before than 1/4sec